# Extracting variables from expression in Lua

Tags: string, lua, lua-table, evaluate

I have expressions in lua which contains standard metatable operations `.__add,.__sub,.__mul, (+,-,*)` 
For example `a+b*xyz-cde`I am trying to extract all free variables in table. For this expression, the table will contain `{a,b,xyz,cde}`. Right now I am trying it with string operations, like splitting, substituting etc. This seems to work but I feel it as ugly way. It gets little complicated as there may nesting and brackets involved in expressions. For example, the expression `(a+b)-c*xyz*(a+(b+c))`  should return table `{a,b,c,xyz}`. Can there be a simple way to extract free variables in expressions? I am even looking for simple way with string library.

Comment: It sounds like you're doing it the right way. If you include the code you're currently using to do this, we might be able to say how you could improve it.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do string processing, it's easy:

```
local V={}
local s="((a+b)-c*xyz*(a+(b+c)))"
for k in s:gmatch("%a+") do
    V[k]=k
end
for k in pairs(V) do print(k) end
```

For fun, you can let Lua do the hard work:

```
local V={}
do
    local _ENV=setmetatable({},{__index=function (t,k) V[k]=k return 0 end})
    local _=((a+b)-c*xyz*(a+(b+c)))
end
for k in pairs(V) do print(k) end
```

This code evaluates the expression in an empty environment where every variable has the value zero, saving the names of the variables in the expression in a table.